# update with case and st_within produces wrong update

Tags: postgis, case-statement

I am using the update below to insert district name from the table *district* into a column in the table *motionslisten*.

*motionslisten* contains point data across the five districts in the municipality and also some data outside the municipality. However, the update only enters the name of one district and enters 'Outside municipality' in all other rows.

When I run an update with the st_within but without the case statement, all rows within the municipality are updated with the correct district, so it must be some error with the case statement or the combination of the case statement and st_within.

I could do the update in two separate steps, but as I need the update for a trigger function, I need to make it work.

Why does it produce the wrong result?

```
update motionslisten m
set district = case
    when st_within(m.wkb_geometry::geometry, d.sdo_geometry::geometry)
    then d.name
    else
    'Outside municipality'
    end
from district d;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having the problem because you don't have a join between motionslist and district with your case statement. So, it's evaluating all combinations of points and districts with that st_within, and of course most of them are 'Outside municipality'.

This update will update the rows you expect:

```
update motionslisten m
set district d.name   
from district d where  st_within(m.wkb_geometry::geometry, d.sdo_geometry::geometry);
```

What's the problem with running two updates in a trigger function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the update which I have working without the case statement.

Comment: And I suppose I could run two consecutive updates in a trigger function. That is probably the solution.